# WebClient.DownloadFile vs. WebClient.DownloadData

Tags: c#, webclient

I am using `WebClient.DownloadFile` to download a small executable file from the internet. This method is working very well. However, I would now like to download this executable file into a byte array rather than onto my hard drive. I did some reading and came across the `WebClient.DownloadData` method. The problem that I am having with the downloadData method is that rather than downloading my *file*, my code is downloading the HTML data behind my file's download page.

I have tried using dozens of sites - each brings me the same issue. Below is the code I am using.

```
// Create a new instance of the System.Net 'WebClient'
        System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

        // Download URL
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www35.multiupload.com:81/files/4D7B4D2BFC3F1A9F765A433BA32ED2C5883D0CE133154A0FDB7E7786547A3165DA62393141C4AF8FF36C75222566CF3EB64AF6FBCFC02099BB209C891529CF7B90C83D9C63D39D989CBB8ECE6DE2B83B/Project1.exe");

        byte[] dbytes = client.DownloadData(uri);

        MessageBox.Show(dbytes.Length.ToString()); // Not the size of my file
```

Keep in mind that I am attempting to download the data of an executable file into a byte array.

Thank you for any help,
Evan

Comment: @Slaks ... I'm sorry but what is Fiddler?

Comment: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ It shows you the actual HTTP request and response

Comment: @Slacks here are my Fiddler logs after attempting to download that file:


# Result Protocol Host URL Body Caching Content-Type Process Comments Custom 
1 302 HTTP www35.multiupload.com:81 /files/4D7B4D2BFC3F1A9F765A433BA32ED2C5883D0CE133154A0FDB7E7786547A3165DA62393141C4AF8FF36C75222566CF3EB64AF6FBCFC02099BB209C891529CF7B90C83D9C63D39D989CBB8ECE6DE2B83B/Project1.exe 0  text/html windowsformsapplication2.vshost:9648   
2 200 HTTP www.multiupload.com /39QMACX7XS 37,505 no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate  Expires: Sun, 10 Jul 2011 04:07:53 GMT text/html windowsformsapplication2.vshost:9648

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to download a file using an expired token url. See below:

URL: http://www35.multiupload.com:81/files/4D7B4D2BFC3F1A9F765A433BA32ED2C5883D0CE133154A0FDB7E7786547A3165DA62393141C4AF8FF36C75222566CF3EB64AF6FBCFC02099BB209C891529CF7B90C83D9C63D39D989CBB8ECE6DE2B83B/Project1.exe`

Server: `www35`

Token:
`4D7B4D2BFC3F1A9F765A433BA32ED2C5883D0CE133154A0FDB7E7786547A3165DA62393141C4AF8FF36C75222566CF3EB64AF6FBCFC02099BB209C891529CF7B90C83D9C63D39D989CBB8ECE6DE2B83B`

You can't just download a file by waiting for the timer to end, and copy the direct link, it's a "token" link. It will only work for a specified period of time before redirecting you back to the download page (which is why you are getting HTML instead of binary data).

**Workaround**

You will have to download the multiupload's HTML and parse the direct download link from the HTML source code. Only this way provides a sure-fire way of getting an up-to-date token url.

Comment: I don't know what the hell I just changed but all of the sudden my original code is now working ... when it hasn't been for an entire week now. Odd ...

Answer (score 0):

How @Dark Slipstream said, you're attempting to download a file using an expired token url
look how get the new url:

```
 System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

        // Download URL
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.multiupload.com/39QMACX7XS");

        byte[] dbytes = client.DownloadData(uri);
        string responseStr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dbytes);
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(responseStr);
        string urlToDownload = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href,'files/')]")[0].Attributes["href"].Value;
        byte[] data = client.DownloadData(uri);
        length = data.Length;
```

I dont parsing the exceptions